# I am trying to program a discord.py bot that saves and names image urls and then can recall the image

Tags: python, discord.py

I am creating a discord bot for me and my friends and would like to be able to have the bot save an image URL as a command. Then whenever that command is called it will recall the saved image URL displaying that image. Basically, if we find a meme or funny picture we want to be able to recall it using a name we can remember.

**Example:**

```
$save dog (image url to dog pic)
Image saved as $dog
$dog
Bot Posts: (image url to dog pic)
```

I am somewhat new to python and I thought making this bot would be a fun way to learn.

I have already tried some code to save the URL and it works, but I am not sure where it saves it. I also need to be able to remove any links that do not work, or if I want to replace an already named image URL. I am using the discord.py rewrite version.

Thank you for any help you can provide!

```
@bot.command(name='save')
async def save_url(ctx, name, *, link):
    await ctx.send('Saved as: $' + name)

    @bot.command(name=name)
    async def send_url(img):
        await img.send(name)
        await img.send(link)

    @bot.command(name=remove)
    async def get_rid(ctx, rid):
        if rid == name:
            name = None
            await ctx.send("Imaged removed")
        elif rid != name:
            await ctx.send("Image could not be found.")
```

**EDIT:**

I think I have found a solution thanks to @Patrick Haugh I added the image URLs to a json file and saved them that way as well as changed the way the imaged is called.

Instead of $(image URL name) its now $img (image URL name)
Here is the code for any other discord.py people, please let me know if I can make it better, or have any critiques!

```
def write_json(title, img):
with open('urls.json') as jfile:
    urldict = json.load(jfile)
    urldict[title] = img
with open('urls.json', 'w') as jfile:
    json.dump(urldict, jfile, sort_keys=True, indent=4)

def delete_json(delete):
    try:
        with open('urls.json') as jfile:
            data = json.loads(jfile.read())
            del data[delete]
        with open('urls.json', 'w') as f:
            json.dump(data, f, sort_keys=True)
        y = 'Image' + delete + 'is removed.'
        return y
    except KeyError:
        e = 'Image ' + delete + ' not found!'
        return e


def read_json(title):
    try:
        with open('urls.json') as jfile:
            get_url = json.load(jfile)
            pic = get_url[title]
            return pic
    except KeyError:
        e = 'Image ' + title + ' not found!'
        return e


def read_json_names():
    with open('urls.json') as jfile:
        get_url = json.load(jfile)
        pic = str(get_url.keys())
        if pic == 'dict_keys([])':
            return 'No images saved!'
        else:
            pic = pic.lstrip('dict_keys([')
            pic = pic.rstrip('])')
            return pic

## bot commands ##########################################

@bot.command(name='save')
async def save_url(ctx, name, *, link):
    write_json(name, link)
    await ctx.send('Saved as: $' + name)


@bot.command(name='remove')
async def remove_url(ctx, thing):
    k = delete_json(thing)
    await ctx.send(k)


@bot.command(name='img')
async def call_url(ctx, call):
    p = read_json(call)
    await ctx.send(p)


@bot.command(name='listimg')
async def call_all_urls(ctx):
    m = read_json_names()
    await ctx.send(m)
```

Comment: Your current code works by registering a new command in the bot itself.  You could write a top level command for removing commands (using [`bot.remove_command`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.remove_command)).  One thing to think about is maybe also storing the name to url mapping to a file so it persists whne your bot needs to be restarted.

Comment: I didn't even think of the top level command! Thank you! Also, What type of file would I use to store the URLs? Would a list in a .txt file work? I would like to be able to save the images if I do ever have to restart.

Comment: I would use a json file, and use the `json` module from the standard library to read/write it into a dictionary. You could also use that dictionary to make sure your remove command doesn't remove the `save_url` command.

Comment: Glad you got it going, I think it's pretty cool btw. only suggestion for an improvement would be to ensure that the image exists are the location when you call the command by checking the return value, just to handle those edge cases where you might get 404's. not 100% if that's viable as not sure all this works, Welcome to python and stack overflow btw